# Inequality in tetrahedron

Tags: inequality

You are given a tetrahedron $ABCD$. $ACB = ADB = 90^\circ$. $AC = CD = DB$. Prove that $AB < 2 * CD$.

I know that $AD = CB$ and $CBD = DCB = ADC = CAD$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle of smallest measure in $\triangle ACB$; note that the angle of smallest measure in $\triangle ADB$ must have the same measure.  Assume that $AC,DB$ are the sides opposite this angle of smallest measure in each of these triangles, since otherwise the claim $AB \lt 2\cdot CD$ will be true automatically.  Since $AC=DB=CD$, the smallest possible value of $\theta$ is $\pi\over 6$, which occurs when $\triangle ABC$ is coplanar with $\triangle ABD$ (which is not a tetrahedron), and the largest possible value of $\theta$ is $\pi\over 4$, since it is one of the angles in a right triangle.

At $\theta=\frac \pi 6$, we have $AB=2\cdot CD$, and at $\theta=\frac \pi4$ we have $AB=\sqrt 2\cdot CD$.  It remains to show that the ratio between $AB$ and $CD$ is decreasing as $\theta$ goes from $\pi\over 6$ to $\pi\over 4$.

First, note that $CD$ lies in a plane $\ell$ such that the midpoint of $CD$ is the point in $\ell$ which is closest to $AB$.  This means that $AC$ has smallest possible length relative to $AB$ when $\theta=\frac\pi 6$, and $AC$ increases in length relative to $AB$ as $\theta$ increases.  But $AC=CD$, so $2\cdot CD \gt AB$ whenever $\theta\gt\frac\pi 6$.

Comment: Why ∠CAD=∠CBD = 0 if θ = π/6 ?

Comment: @user4201961:  $\theta=\frac \pi 6$ then the "tetrahedron" is flat and has three sides along a regular hexagon with the fourth side being a diagonal of this hexagon.  Having $\theta$ any smaller creates a shape that cannot match the initial conditions where $AC=DB=CD$

Comment: But what is the proof of ∠CAD=∠CBD=0? If θ = 30*, then ∠CBD angle is equal to 30* (because CB = x*sqrt(3), CD = x, BD = x, so from the law of cosine, we derive that ∠CBD is equal to 30*)

Comment: Oops, you're right, I picked the wrong angle that is zero.  What I meant is the angle between two of the faces of the tetrahedron: $\triangle ABC,\triangle ABD$.  The angle between these two planes will be $0$ when $\theta=\frac\pi6$.  I mistakenly equated this planar angle with $\angle CAD, \angle CBD$.

Comment: @user4201961: another way to say it is that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ABD$ will be coplanar when $\theta=\frac\pi6$.

Comment: But how to prove that △ABC and △ABD will be coplanar?

Comment: Good question, let me think about that.

Comment: The simple answer is to say, suppose that $\theta=\frac\pi6$ and $\triangle ABC,\triangle ABD$ are not coplanar.  Then $AC=\frac 12 AB=BD$.  Note that if $AB$ is the diagonal of a regular hexagon, the sides of said hexagon will have length $AC=CD=BD=\frac 12AB$, and there will be three sides of this hexagon between intersections with $AB$, and these sides will be coplanar.  Then the vertices of the hexagon lie on a circle, and thus are each the right-angle corner of a right triangle with alternative angles $\frac \pi 3,\frac\pi 6$.  But then $CD$ must be greater than each of $AC,BD$, since...

Comment: ... it is not in the plane with the other two sides, but the other two sides are part of right-angle triangles.

Comment: @user4201961: this is just an argument answer so far, I'll work on a proper edit to my answer and post it when I've put it together.